# How to submit 2 forms with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, form-submit

I am submitting 2 forms via AJAX:

```
$("#form1").on("submit", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  var action_url = $(this).attr("action");
  var postData = $(this).serializeArray();

  $.post(action_url,postData,function(data){
    var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
    if(obj.status == "error")
    {
    // Code
  };

  if(obj.status == "success")
  {
    // Code
  }
});

});
```

`#form2` is submitted the same way, with precisely the same code above (switching out the selector and using different results for `error` and `success`).

Is there a simple way I can submit both forms with one button?

*** EDIT ***

Form HTML below:

```
<form id="form1" action="url1/action1" method="post">
 // code
</form>
<form id="form2" action="url2/action2" method="post">
 // code
</form>
```

Comment: Do you want to combine the data from both forms into one submission, or just submit each form to the same URL one right after the other?

Comment: @Blazemonger just submit each form; `action_url` is different in each case.

Comment: You could just add `$('#form2').trigger('submit')` inside your first `submit` handler, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form#form1").on("submit", function(event){
```

and

```
$("form#form2").on("submit", function(event){
```

Answer (score -1):

Just combine both forms into one. There is no reason that data displayed on the screen in two places can't be one form behind the scenes.

Comment: The forms submit to two different URLs.

Comment: Yes. But if he controls the thing the forms are submitting to then he can change that. If not then the answer is no use to him and he'll have to do it the harder way but lets rule out simple first :)